# A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

this is the exception

```
System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtCodeFormate="<a href="%%strpath%%...").
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateHttpValueCollection(HttpValueCollection collection, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_HasForm()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod(Boolean dontReturnNull)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.ccadmin_cms_setup_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Till now I've tried following options,

```
 <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
 <pages validateRequest="false" enableEventValidation="false"></pages>
```

FYI, its working fine in local, but when I deploy it on server its not working properly,
Do I need to work on something at IIS ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your question with all options answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17258129/1849444).

Have you tried the following after you modify `Web.config`?

Option 1: On the model add this attribute to each property that you need to allow HTML - best choice

```
[AllowHtml]
```

Option 2: On the controller action add this attribute to allow all HTML

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
```

Comment: But this is ASP.NET web forms,How can I use this attributes in ASPX pages?

Comment: Here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16590834/1849444) they say the issue is that you using `targetFramework="4.5"`. Can you change to `4.0` and try again? Or this is signifisant for you to use `4.5`?

Comment: Nope, for one page, I cannot target whole application to 4.0 framework